Being unable to run the Xamarin project in Visual Studio for MAC
When attempting to run a Xamarin project in Visual Studio for Mac, the simulators are not appearing, and only the Generic Simulator is displayed. The Visual Studio version is 17.6.14 (build 413), and the Xcode version is 16.1.

How can I resolve this issue?

VSMac is no longer supported and will not work with newer versions of XCode

@Jason could you provide which extensions I need to use on Visual Studio Code to develop the .NET MAUI and Xamarin projects.

this is well documented
